# ResolvePackageNotFound error: when creating Conda environment

Tags: python, conda

I'm trying to run project:

```
https://github.com/ryanlayer/COvid19
```

I am trying to execute all of it as it is.

But when I execute command to create new conda environment and install package list from `environment.yml` file I get the following error:

```
ResolvePackageNotFound: 
  - icu==58.2=h4b95b61_1
  - scipy==1.4.1=py36h9fa6033_0
  - libtiff==4.1.0=hcb84e12_0
  - tk==8.6.8=ha441bb4_0
  - pcre==8.43=h0a44026_0
  - hdf4==4.2.13=h39711bb_2
  - libxml2==2.9.9=hf6e021a_1
  - ncurses==6.2=h0a44026_0
  - statsmodels==0.11.0=py36h1de35cc_0
  - giflib==5.1.4=h1de35cc_1
  - json-c==0.13.1=h3efe00b_0
  - expat==2.2.6=h0a44026_0
  - zstd==1.3.7=h5bba6e5_0
  - matplotlib-base==3.1.3=py36h9aa3819_0
  - openssl==1.1.1g=h1de35cc_0
  - pyproj==1.9.6=py36h9c430a6_0
  - bzip2==1.0.8=h1de35cc_0
  - libedit==3.1.20181209=hb402a30_0
  - libcurl==7.67.0=h051b688_0
  - zlib==1.2.11=h1de35cc_3
  - sqlite==3.31.1=h5c1f38d_1
  - cairo==1.14.12=hc4e6be7_4
  - libcxxabi==4.0.1=hcfea43d_1
  - libspatialindex==1.9.3=h0a44026_0
  - shapely==1.6.4=py36he8793f5_0
  - mkl_random==1.1.0=py36ha771720_0
  - xz==5.2.5=h1de35cc_0
  - cython==0.29.15=py36h0a44026_0
  - jpeg==9b=he5867d9_2
  - geos==3.7.1=h0a44026_0
  - intel-openmp==2019.4=233
  - libiconv==1.15=hdd342a3_7
  - libpng==1.6.37=ha441bb4_0
  - glib==2.63.1=hd977a24_0
  - krb5==1.16.4=hddcf347_0
  - libdap4==3.19.1=h3d3e54a_0
  - fontconfig==2.13.0=h5d5b041_1
  - cycler==0.10.0=py36hfc81398_0
  - hdf5==1.10.4=hfa1e0ec_0
  - libgfortran==3.0.1=h93005f0_2
  - libssh2==1.9.0=ha12b0ac_1
  - tornado==6.0.4=py36h1de35cc_1
  - numpy==1.18.1=py36h7241aed_0
  - fiona==1.8.4=py36h9a122fd_0
  - libpq==11.2=h051b688_0
  - pixman==0.38.0=h1de35cc_0
  - kealib==1.4.7=hf5ed860_6
  - kiwisolver==1.1.0=py36h0a44026_0
  - mkl==2019.4=233
  - libgdal==2.3.3=h0950a36_0
  - libnetcdf==4.6.1=hd5207e6_2
  - mkl-service==2.3.0=py36hfbe908c_0
  - libboost==1.67.0=hebc422b_4
  - readline==7.0=h1de35cc_5
  - mkl_fft==1.0.15=py36h5e564d8_0
  - curl==7.67.0=ha441bb4_0
  - freetype==2.9.1=hb4e5f40_0
  - numpy-base==1.18.1=py36h6575580_1
  - openjpeg==2.3.0=hb95cd4c_1
  - proj4==5.2.0=h0a44026_1
  - python==3.6.10=hfe9666f_1
  - pandas==1.0.3=py36h6c726b0_0
  - gdal==2.3.3=py36hbe65578_0
  - libcxx==4.0.1=hcfea43d_1
  - poppler==0.65.0=ha097c24_1
  - libspatialite==4.3.0a=h644ec7d_19
  - gettext==0.19.8.1=h15daf44_3
  - xerces-c==3.2.2=h44e365a_0
  - freexl==1.0.5=h1de35cc_0
  - libkml==1.3.0=hbe12b63_4
```

I first tried this in `Windows` and get the same error, now I'm using `Ubuntu` and the problem persisted, so I do not think it is an issue of the OS I use.

Comment: Did you try this command? `conda env create -f environment.yml`

Comment: Their YAML is missing the `conda-forge` channel, which [is standard for Bioconda](https://bioconda.github.io/user/install.html#set-up-channels). Edit the YAML to include the channel `conda-forge` directly above the `bioconda` channel, then rerun the `conda env create`.

Comment: In addition to what @merv said, those package requirements are likely over-specified, which could also lead to some issues.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to install conda-forge packages, specify it in your yaml file.

For example, I want to install "poppler". It's a conda-forge package (`conda install -c conda-forge poppler`), so I created a yaml file like below:

```
name: myEnv
channels:
  - defaults
dependencies:
- python==3.8
- pip
- conda-forge::poppler=22.04.0
- pip:
  # works for regular pip packages
  - opencv-python==4.6.0.66
```

As you see I add `channels` and also specified the conda-forge for `proppler`.